# How to let Windows know that a file is "being used" by my application?

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I'm making a simple VB.net application, which basically asks the user for multiple files and **later** it will need to access the selected files and modify them.

Right now, I'm saving the full paths of the selected files, and in the future, the application will iterate through each path, open the file from such path, and modify it.

The problem with that is that the user could select a file (so the full path is saved) and then they delete or move the file before my application modifies it.

Normally, I'd throw an error saying "File not found", but I'm under the impression that Windows had a feature that would disallow you from deleting/moving/renaming a file because "a program was using it" - which is a feature that would fit way better for my application.

I'm not very advanced with VB.NET, but I suppose that if I "open" a file using my application (with some IO thing), the feature I mentioned earlier would indeed trigger and the user would be unable to modify the file because it is "opened" by my application.

However, since my only desire is to "reserve" files, it seems to be quite wasteful to actually open them when I don't really need to (yet). Is there a way to tell Windows I need a certain file to be intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening files (with specifying desired sharing mode) is the way to do that.

I don't believe there is anything really wrong with opening multiple files (also you still will not be able to do anything for cases like removing of removable drive). In old times there were restrictions on number of opened files per process, but I it no longer practical limitation - [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy solution: open each file in exclusive mode.
It should look like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim FS = System.IO.File.Open("path", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, IO.FileShare.None)
End Sub
```

But beware: You have opened a file handle and if you code responsible for closing files fails without terminating the application files will still be locked for very long (till app shuts down).
You can use a using clause or a try/catch/finally clause - I don't know enough about your program to recommend anyone.

Comment: +0: Not sure about your second half - if application is terminated irrespective of a reason all handles are closed... Not sure what problem you are trying to describe.

Comment: I might be wrong: but the handles may be closed a long time afterwards - which looks weird to the user. So better close them explicitly.
Also: If the user starts multiple operations without closing the program, he might run into this issue too

Comment: To my knowledge handles are closed as soon as process is terminated. On other hand (which is probably what you trying to say) if app does not terminate, but code that responsible for closing files does not work correctly files will be locked for very long time till app is terminate.

Comment: Inlined comments - see you are ok with the change. (+1 without statement that looked like handles can stay open after app is terminated).